# Django - how to make requests with proxies?

Tags: python, django

I am following this guide: https://ultimatedjango.com/blog/how-to-consume-rest-apis-with-django-python-reques/

I am wondering how to make these requests using proxies? I am thinking that this part should be modified:

```
def save_embed(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitEmbed(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data['url']
            r = requests.get('http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=' + settings.EMBEDLY_KEY + '&url=' + url)
```

Is there easier way ? I would like to use the same proxy every time for the same API key. (2-3 api keys)
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a ["proxies" argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) to the request.get method containing a dictionary of proxy servers to use for different protocols, so your code becomes.

```
def save_embed(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SubmitEmbed(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data['url']
            proxies = {
                "http": "http://123.123.123.123:1234",
                "https": "https://123.123.123.123:1234",
            }
            r = requests.get('http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?key=' + settings.EMBEDLY_KEY + '&url=' + url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure proxies by setting the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:3128"
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:1080"

$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://example.org')
```

Ref: https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

This method is suggested if you are using it on a local development environment where the responding server only serves requests from white-listed IP's.